# 301 Redirects in WordPress - Some Work, Some Don't

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I am having a weird issue after transferring a client's website from HTML to a WordPress theme.

I'm using the plugin "Simple 301 Redirects" to forward all the old HTML pages to the updated WordPress URLs - about 50 total redirects.

This plugin has worked great for me on a number of other websites, but for some reason, the 301 redirect works for about half of those URLs, and the other half I receive a 404 Page Not Found error.

I attempted to remove one of the non-working redirects from the plug-in, and manually place this within the .htaccess file, but that didn't work either.

Any idea as to why that may be the case, and what is the best way to process a long list of 301 redirects for a WordPress website?

EDIT: Here is my .htaccess, and I actually got this one to work.  As of now, I have 42 redirects working using "Simple 301 Redirects" plug-in, and there are 17 that are not working using the same plug-in.

```
Options -Indexes

# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^articles\.html$ http://www.magnuminvestigations.net/articles/ [R=301,L]

RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

And here is an example that is not currently working:

Old URL

```
http://www.magnuminvestigations.net/cheating_infidelity_investigators.html‎
```

New URL

```
http://www.magnuminvestigations.net/services/cheating-and-infidelity-investigations/
```

Comment: Post you rewrite rule and a URL that doesn't work.

Comment: I just updated my post with my htaccess file.  This rewrite rule is actually working.  As you can see in my edit, I have 17 redirects which aren't working (16 actually if you count the example above).  Do you think I should do all 301's within the .htaccess, or just the ones that aren't currently working?

Comment: I'd do whatever you did to make that one work. As long as the redirect is being caught somewhere, it's all good. Odd that it would work for some and not others

Comment: Okay, I have literally no idea what is going on.  What is the best tool to test 301's?  I just clicked on the old URL listed in Google's index, and I got a 404.  Then I copied and pasted that same URL, and it redirected without an issue.  Then I tried the exact same thing a minute later and now it's not redirecting at all.  In that time, I did not update one piece of code.

Comment: That is really weird, rules cannot change on their own too

Comment: This has to be a browser thing.  If I click on the HTML link from Google's search listing, I will get the 404 error for a handful of links.  Yet if I copy and paste that same URL from my spreadsheet, it will re-direct properly.  When I get the 404 error, even if I refresh, it doesn't redirect.  Makes no sense to me, so if anyone could explain, that would be great!